# How to add dynamic content to Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal, that is launched initially via a button.
Inside is a form with select dropdowns, depending on the selection option the modal must update with another select box from the db. Here is the modal. Depending on "Make" the div "Models" is loaded via jQuery `.html()`. Hoewever, I cannot get the dynamic `select` box "Models" loaded into the modal, .`html()` is not working, any suggestions?

```
 <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">New Car Request</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control">
             <?php foreach($years as $year) { ?>
                 <option value="<?=$year["Year"]?>"><?=$year["Year"]?></option>
             <?php } ?>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" id="vehicle-make">
             <?php foreach($makes as $make) { ?>
                 <option value="<?=$make["Make"]?>"><?=$make["Make"]?></option>
             <?php } ?>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div id="models"></div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myModal = $('.modal').modal();

        $("#vehicle-make").on("change", function(e) {
            var make = $(this).val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("/ajax.php", { make: make, method: "get_model_by_make" }, function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    $(myModal + " #models").html(data.models);
                }
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$("#models").html(data.models);` ?

Comment: I tried that first, then thought to add the parent. Still doesn't work.

Comment: try taking out the "e.preventDefault();" line - you don't need to prevent the default action here. then, could try console.log(data) when your ajax request returns? just to double check exactly what you're getting back.